# What does “we’re it” mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, expressions

> As their common name implies, house crows (Corvus splendens) stick
>   pretty closely to people. So much so that there are no known
>   populations living independently of us. You might say that, in so far
>   as these birds have a ‘natural environment’, **we’re it**.

I'm not sure what this last part of the last sentence means. I'd guess the meaning was "we can't do much about it," but this is just my intuition. I've also googled up some definitions meaning "we're a team," but it doesn't seem to make sense in this context. The words are short and as common as they get, which didn't make my research attempts any easier. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: "It" refers to "natural environment". It's not an idiom, so you won't find anything online. We are the crows natural environment.

Comment: @jimm has it. It may help you to know the writing style is a little playful: "stick pretty closely to" and "we're it." Tagging someone as _It_ also hints at the game of tag: "Tag - You're IT!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You might say that, in so far as these birds have a ‘natural environment’, **we’re it**.

In this case *it* is referring to the house crow's natural environment and *we* is referring to people.

So in this case "we’re it" is stating that "people are their natural environment".

Comment: Argh! It seems plain as day now that I see it. Thank you so very much!